# Error creating a plot in MATLAB using values I got from excel using actxserver.

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Hello so I am attempting to write a MATLAB script that reads multiple excel files at ones and gathers values from the worksheet. through some research I found that using actxserver is a very quick way to get the data. The values are stored in the out and out1 variables and by using vertcat function I create an array that has all the 300,000 values that I need to store. This seems to work. However when I try to plot the values in a simple x vs y graph using plot I get an error that states:

Error using plot
Not enough input arguments.

Error in opener (line 36)
plot(out0,out1)

Below is the code. I am sure it is a simple fix but I have looked and not found anything helpful.

```
  clc;


filename = 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\DASYLab\13.0.0\eng\data\TRIAL\';

D = dir([filename, '\*.csv']);
Num = length(D(not([D.isdir])));

f = Num;
ex = actxserver('excel.application');

o = 0;
k = 0;

for i=1:f



 if(i<=10)
 ex.Workbooks.Open([filename,'mydataIII_0',num2str(i-1)]);
 else 
 ex.Workbooks.Open([filename,'mydataIII_',num2str(i-1)]);
 end

  out0 = get(ex.Range('A8:A40967'),'Value');
  out = vertcat(o,out0);
  o = out;   


  out1 = get(ex.Range('C8:C40967'),'Value');
  outone = vertcat(k,out1);
  k = outone;

end

figure;
plot(out0,out1)

ex.Quit
```

Comment: before plotting, try writing on a line just `out0`  and see what output you get. This will tell you something about the form of that data, and you should be able to figure out what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Hello sorry I but I figured it out. The issue was that when the get function was used to get the value it created a cell array.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html

if you want to convert the data to a ordinary array one can use the cell2mat() function